# Connect two ssh tunnels

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, tunnel

I have 3 systems. Lets call them A, B and C.

I need to create a ssh tunnel from A to C. But there are some restrictions:

- A can not connect to B
- A can not connect to C
- C can not connect to A

However, I can create a tunnel from B to A and a tunnel from B to C.

How can I connect those tunnels to create a tunnel from A to C?

B is running Windows 10, while A and C are Linux systems.

Comment: can you just choose a port on B, use remote port forwarding (i.e. reverse port forwarding) from B to A and local port forwarding (the normal kind) from B to C? Only downside: programs on B can enter the tunnel at B

Comment: From B: `ssh -R 2022:C:22`, then from A: `ssh -p 2022 127.0.0.1`